# Java Swing MVP unit testing with Mockito

Tags: java, unit-tests, gui, java-gui

**Description**

I have a simple Java Swing application implementing the Model-View-Presenter pattern. My aim is to be able to test the logic behind "rendering" the view.

[image]

Here is the presenter and associated interface:

```
public class MainPresenter implements IViewListener
{
    private final IMainWindow _view;
    private final ITaxCalculator _model;

    public MainPresenter(IMainWindow view, ITaxCalculator model)
    {
        this._view = view;
        this._model = model;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCalculateButtonClicked(double amount)
    {
        // perform calculations
        this._model.setTotalSales(salesAmount);
        double countySalesTax = this._model.getCountySalesTax();
        double stateSalesTax = this._model.getStateSalesTax();
        double totalSalesTax = this._model.getTotalSalesTax();

        // update the view
        this._view.setCountySalesTaxField(countySalesTax);
        this._view.setStateSalesTaxField(stateSalesTax);
        this._view.setTotalSalesTaxField(totalSalesTax);
    }
}

public interface IViewListener
{
    public void onCalculateButtonClicked(double amount);
}
```

Here is the model and its associated interface:

```
public interface ITaxCalculator
{
    public double getCountySalesTax();
    public double getStateSalesTax();
    public double getTotalSalesTax();
    public void setTotalSales(double totalSales);
}

public class TaxCalculator implements ITaxCalculator
{
    protected double _totalSales;
    
    public TaxCalculator()
    {
        
    }
    
    public TaxCalculator(double totalSales)
    {
        this._totalSales = totalSales;
    }
    
    public void setTotalSales(double totalSales)
    {
        this._totalSales = totalSales;
    }
    
    public double getCountySalesTax()
    {
        return 0.02 * this._totalSales;
    }
    
    public double getStateSalesTax()
    {
        return 0.04 * this._totalSales;
    }
    
    public double getTotalSalesTax()
    {
        return this.getCountySalesTax() + this.getStateSalesTax();
    }//getTotalSalesTax
}//class
```

Here is the interface which the view implements (I've omitted the actual view which extends JFrame, as that is quite a lot of code):

```
public interface IMainWindow
{
    public void addListener(IViewListener listener);
    
    public double getSalesAmountEntered();
    public void setSalesAmountEntered(double amount);
    
    public double getCountySalesTaxField();
    public void setCountySalesTaxField(double amount);
    
    public double getStateSalesTaxField();
    public void setStateSalesTaxField(double amount);
    
    public double getTotalSalesTaxField();
    public void setTotalSalesTaxField(double amount);
    
    public void clear();
}
```

**Unit testing problems**

I'm using JUnit 4 and Mockito (here is an extract from my `pom.xml` file):

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.13.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-inline</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.7</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Now, I am trying to unit-test the presenter class. I normally work with C#, and only just started with Java. I've implemented a similar MVP pattern with WinForms before, using FakeItEasy for unit testing. In that situation, I might do something like the following, and it yields the expected results:

```
// arrange
var fakeView = A.Fake<IMainWindow>();
A.CallTo(() => fakeView.GetAmount()).Returns(100);
var fakeModel = A.Fake<ITaxCalculator>();
var presenter = new MainPresenter(fakeView, fakeModel);
```

In this particular example, I am trying to achieve something similar with the following JUnit test.

```
public class MainPresenter_Test
{
    @Mock
    IMainWindow mockView;
    
    @Mock
    ITaxCalculator mockModel;
    
    @Before
    public void setUp()
    {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }
    
    @Test
    public void onCalculateButtonClicked_Test()
    {
        // arrange
        double amount = 100;
        when(mockView.getSalesAmountEntered()).thenReturn(amount);
        when(mockModel.getCountySalesTax()).thenReturn(2.00);
        when(mockModel.getStateSalesTax()).thenReturn(4.00);
        when(mockModel.getTotalSalesTax()).thenReturn(6.00);
        MainPresenter presenter = new MainPresenter(mockView, mockModel);
        
        // act
        presenter.onCalculateButtonClicked(mockView.getSalesAmountEntered());
        double actualCountySalesTax = mockView.getCountySalesTaxField();
        double actualStateSalesTax = mockView.getStateSalesTaxField();
        double actualTotalSalesTax = mockView.getTotalSalesTaxField();
        
        // assert
        assertEquals(2.00, actualCountySalesTax, 0);
    }
```

However, the assert fails, because the actual value is always 0. Am I doing something wrong in the setup of the unit test?